# Determine the normality of sulfuric acid solution, given that it gives a yellow color with methyl orange and a red color with methyl red

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, ph

Determine the normality of sulfuric acid solution, given that it gives a yellow color with methyl orange and a red color with methyl red.[image]

can someone help me with this? what should do first?

i know that normality = (grams of solute)*(factor) / (MW of solute)*(liters of solution)

Comment: Please use proper names and symbols for physical quantities and make sure it is clear what belongs to numerator and what to denominator. For example, "g of solute" is illiterate and should be replaced, I presume, with mass $m.$ What is "*factor*"? Please visit [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [this page](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/) and [this one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/) on how to format your posts better with MathJax and Markdown.

Comment: It is an incomplete question. If your teacher wrote this question, ask him/her what is in the flask and what is in the burette? Only then we can decide which indicator is to be used. Also you need a balanced equation, you also need to know the volume of the acid and the base.

Comment: @andselisk, *factor* is the same 18th century conversion factor between molarity and normality. I don't know when this syllabus would be updated.

Comment: Right, so OP probably should be aware that IUPAC, SI and ISO consider this "*factor*" (which should really be called an *equivalent*) deprecated for decades. If you need a brief, easy-to-access and authoritative document to use in discussion with the normality apologists, feel free to use https://doi.org/10.1515/pac-2017-0410.

Comment: As the first step, determine [H+]

Comment: The pH of the solution should be $4.4$. So now do calculate [$\ce{H+}$] and here you are.

Comment: thanks! can you help me check if I did it right? here's the link to my solution: 
https://preview.redd.it/wr9rz7pv6em61.jpg?width=355&format=pjpg&auto=webp&s=75ecd0f5694d78a00f85e9644714a88a9a2f1f80